# Does Google Play Service API (location services) require a data plan?

Tags: android, google-play

What I am reading about play services is that it uses an API key, which implies it must have Internet access to work. Is this true?

The application I am working on must work **without** Internet access.

Answer (score 1):

There are **many** pieces to the Play Services SDK. Some require API keys (e.g., Maps V2). Some do not (e.g., the fused location API).

> The application I am working on must work without Internet access.

Then you are going to need to limit yourself to portions of the Play Services SDK that do not require an API key and do not have an intrinsic need for Internet access. I do not know if the fused location API needs Internet access to be useful.

Comment: In my case 'location services' means getting gps fence notifications. Everything else is optional.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out **initializing** your code with the API-key does not require Internet access. So I can use the google libraries for GPS in my app and not worry about having a data plan.